# How to write binary data to file and keep the file open in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, node.js-fs

I need to write a sequence of boolean and float values to a file in binary using Javascript. I would like to keep the file open and then just do a sequence of writes. Here is the pseudocode of what I would like to accomplish

```
file = open('filename.dat', 'ab') // open in "append binary" mode
file.write(true); // write 1 bit to file
file.write(3.14) // write 64 bit float number to file
file.close()
```

Does anyone know how to do this in Javascript? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Create the binary data you want in the file in a Buffer object and then write the Buffer to the file.  If you want to keep the file open, just don't call `.close()`.

Comment: Note [Buffer methods](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) such as `.writeDoubleLE()` and `.writeUint8()` that let you write a Javascript number and an unsigned 8-bit value to a buffer.

Comment: Thanks it worked. The trick was to use a createWriteStream and a buffer.